# Sort string inside list to first position if contains particular characters?

Tags: python

I have this case:

```
list = ["Translate:(0,0,0)", "Scale:(1,1,1)", "Rotate:(0,180,0)"]
str = "Rotate:"
```

And I want to sort this list based on incoming string str in this case is "Rotate:" so the item that contains "Rotate:" goes to the first position in the list. I don't care about the order of the rest of the elements.  Something like this:

```
["Rotate:(0,180,0)", "Scale:(1,1,1)", "Translate:(0,0,0)"]
```

Is that possible by using  "sorted" function with `key = lambda ...` and so on or `cmp`? 
Or I have to do more complex looping and comparison to rebuild the list?

Comment: `list` and `str` are python reserved words, dont use them as variable names!

Comment: `sorted(lst, key=lambda x: ('Rotate:' not in x, x))` (depending on : `False < True`)

Comment: The other keys here start with S and T, which happen to sort after R; is that guaranteed for all keys, or could there be keys like `"Affine-Transform"` that naturally sort before `Rotate`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `str_ in x` as key:

```
>>> list_ = ["Translate:(0,0,0)","Scale:(1,1,1)", "Rotate:(0,180,0)"]
>>> str_ = "Rotate:"
>>> sorted(list_, key=lambda x:str_ in x, reverse=True)
['Rotate:(0,180,0)', 'Translate:(0,0,0)', 'Scale:(1,1,1)']
```

Comment: `list` and `str` are python reserved words, dont use them as variable names, use other variable names

Comment: Thanks a lot!This is great. This is what I tried first time but I didn't use reverse = True.

Answer (score 1):

```
def bring_to_front(lst, match_str):
    """
    Given a list of strings and a match string,
    return a copy of the list with all items
    beginning with match_str moved to the head of the list
    """
    return sorted(lst, key = lambda s: s.startswith(match_str), reverse=True)
```

then

```
>>> lst = ["Translate:(0,0,0)", "Rotate:(0,0,90)", "Scale:(1,1,1)", "Rotate:(0,180,0)"]
>>> bring_to_front(lst, "Rotate:")
['Rotate:(0,0,90)', 'Rotate:(0,180,0)', 'Translate:(0,0,0)', 'Scale:(1,1,1)']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if "Rot" in word: # "Rotate()" returns True
    liste.remove(word) # remove the word
    liste.insert(0, word) # insert it again as first position
```